# Как вместо цикла использовать встроенные функции pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, оптимизация

Есть такой data frame

[image]

Надо сделать следующее:
таблицу new заполнить следующим образом.
Если разность period_id i-ой строчки и (i-1) строчки больше чем 1, то на i-ую строчку столбца new добавляется единичка

[image]

сделал используя цикл

[image]

Но, такой цикл считает 5 сек для 10000 значений, значений там вообще 800000)
Как это сделать без цикла? например используя функции pandas?

Comment: Для чего нужен первый  if?

Comment: Для того чтобы для каждого нового магазина(store_id) высчитывалось независимо, а не продолжала расти переменная в столбце new

Comment: Так все равно будет расти - вы ж нигде не начинаете с единицы.

Comment: пожалуйста, приводите исходные данные и код в виде текста, а не скриншотов. не ленитесь. вы же не хотите получить ответ в виде фотографии?

Answer (score 3):

Можно сгруппировать DF по `store_id` и для каждой группы расчитать разницу `period_id` по отношению к предыдущей строке и для тех строк, где разница больше `1` посчитать кумулятивную сумму.

Пример:

исходный DataFrame:

```
In [8]: data
Out[8]:
   store_id  period_id  new
0         1          1    1
1         1          2    1
2         1          4    1
3         1          5    1
4         1          8    1
5         2          1    1
6         2          4    1
7         2          5    1
```

решение:

```
In [9]: data["new"] += \
            data.groupby("store_id")["period_id"].apply(lambda x: x.diff().gt(1).cumsum())
```

результат:

```
In [10]: data
Out[10]:
   store_id  period_id  new
0         1          1    1
1         1          2    1
2         1          4    2
3         1          5    2
4         1          8    3
5         2          1    1
6         2          4    2
7         2          5    2
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Помогло!)

Comment: @nikakishmaria, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) ;)

Comment: @nikakishmaria, [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)